# When a function is defined at some point, does limit exist at that specific point?

Tags: calculus

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2, & x<1\\
2.4, & x=1\\
x^2+1, &x>1
\end{cases}
$$
Does $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ exist?

The values of one-sided limits are different for the function $f(x)$ at $x=1$, but at $x=1$ the function is, $f(x)=2.4$. My question is, does this function has limit at $x=1$?

Comment: What does it mean for the limit to exist at $x=1$? Apply the definition

Comment: It does not and you have proved that  the limit does not exist!

Comment: well, by checking the two sided limits for this function, it's clear that two sided limit at x=1 doesn't exist for this function.  I was curious about the fact that at x=1, f(x)= 2.4 has any effects on determining the limit?

Comment: The value of $f(1)$ doesn't matter in this case, correct. It matters more for the sake of continuity, not the existence of the limit itself.

Comment: okay, I got it now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, for a limit to exist at a point,

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L \;\;\;\;\; \text{if and only if} \;\;\;\;\; \lim_{x \to c^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to c^-} f(x) = L$$

Or, in words, the limit at a point exists and is equal to $L$, if and only if the limit from each side is also equal to $L$. (Note: it need not be true that the limit as $x \to c$ is equal to $f(c)$ for existence to occur.)

For example, consider the step function:

$$u(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix}
0 & x \le 0 \\
1 & x > 0
\end{matrix} \right.$$

What is the limit as $x \to 0$? If you approach from the left, it's $0$, and if you approach from the right it's $1$. Therefore, the limit as $x \to 0$ for $u(x)$ doesn't exist, since you get a different limit of approach on each side, i.e.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} u(x) \; \text{doesn't exist, because}  \; 1 = \lim_{x \to 0^-} u(x) \ne \lim_{x \to 0^+} u(x) = 0$$

This can be seen graphically: see that "jump" at $x = 0$?

[image]

In your scenario, you're correct: the limit as $x \to 1$ from each side is different for your $f$. Therefore, you rightfully can conclude that the limit does not exist.

---

You can read more on the existence of limits on [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/when-does-a-limit-exist/).